# htaccess if contains /confirm-post/, then go to the folder and access/open index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Have url like this

```
domain.com/confirm-post/Got7oX
```

In .htaccess want to define rule: If url contains `confirm-post` then go to folder `confirm-post`. In the folder i have `index.php` so want to open `index.php`

Defined such rule (exception)

```
RewriteRule ^confirm-post - [L]
```

if url is `domain.com/confirm-post/` then i can open index.php

but for `domain.com/confirm-post/Got7oX` displays another page

What need to change/add to

```
RewriteRule ^confirm-post - [L]
```

A bit modified the aim. If url contains `confirm-post` then instead of the url present (open) another file and part of url after `confirm-post` use for `$_GET['confirm-post']`

And this seems works

```
RewriteRule ^confirm-post/(.+)$ another-file.php?confirm-post=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^confirm-post/.+ - [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work... Displays another page